# WinForms designer

Tags: c#, winforms, designer

I have a large number of forms with a lot of controls on them and i need to do specific actions with certain groups of controls. Is it possible to select all elements with the same type using vs winforms designer? or using other instruments?
It's not a problem when i'm using custom controls where i can implement my own controlDesigner and override Verbs property (for example), but unfortunately most of them are common.

Answer (score 0):

"I need to do specific actions with certain groups of controls" is pretty vague. If you are trying to change or insert a property to controls with a specific name or property value, you could try a global search and replace of the form.designer.cs files. Depending on what you're changing, this will be used by, overwritten by, or completely break the designer.

If you want a better answer you will have to describe what you're trying to do.